# Access domain name via local IP

Tags: dns, ip, localhost

I've setup a local server but I cannot remember how to access specific domains through a single IP, example:

I have the domain setup in `hosts` as:

```
127.0.0.1 zf2-tutorial.localhost localhost
127.0.0.1 DomainA
127.0.0.1 DomainB
```

Now when I access my local server through my ip address of: `172.16.20.35` it comes up at the first domain `zf2`.

I'm trying to access DomainA through local IP, can anyone tell me how to do this with a browser?

I've tried `172.16.20.35:DomainA`, `172.16.20.35.DomainA`, `172.16.20.35/DomainA`.

Comment: I don't really get it. Why don't you just enter `DomainA` into your browser's address bar?

Comment: Because that's not going to the local server, the domain isn't based on the computer that I'm try to access.

Comment: okay.... then why don't you have `172.16.20.35  DomainA` in your `hosts` file?